# Object not being replaced

Tags: java

I have two lists of contacts, and I want to replace one with another as:

```
private PhoneCAdapter getContactAdapter(ArrayList<UserAgenda> phoneContacts) throws NetworkConnetionException {     
    List<UserAgenda> serverContacts = WithingsAPI.getInstance().getContactListByType(Common.CONTACT_LIST_TYPE_FILE,"ALL");

    for(UserAgenda pc: phoneContacts){                  
        for(UserAgenda sc : serverContacts){
            if(pc.getEmails() != null){
                ArrayList<String> emailsPc = new ArrayList<String>(pc.getEmails());
                for(String epc: emailsPc){                      
                    ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<String>(sc.getEmails());                    
                    String emailServer = emailList.get(0);//server contact has only one email                   
                    if(epc.equals(emailServer)){//we have to substitute the object from the server with the phone ones.
                        pc = sc;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    PhoneCAdapter ca = new PhoneCAdapter(this, 0, phoneContacts,PhoneContacts.this );
    return ca;
}
```

But after the loops my variable phoneContacts still has the same values. Only if I change the fields manually as:

```
if(epc.equals(emailServer)){
    pc.setUserOfWW(sc.getUserOfWW());                           
    if(sc.getInvited().equals("true")){                             
       pc.setInvited("true");                           
    }
    else{
        pc.setInvited("false");//here we have people who are/arent user of WW
        pc.setId2invite(sc.getId2invite());
    }
}
```

How could I replace my object with info from the phone with the user I get from the server, without doing it manually for each field?

Comment: Yes, you haven't made any changes to `phoneContacts`. Changing the value of the local variable `pc` to refer to a different object doesn't change the collection...

Comment: But I can change it manually. I would like to do the same with the reference of the object.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, but if you want the collection to refer to a different object, you need to make that change explicitly. Changing the local variable *will not* make that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the local variable you're using for the iterator *doesn't* change the content of the collection. It's very important that you understand the difference between modifying the object that a variable's value refers to, and modifying a variable. If you modify the object that the reference within a list refers to, that change will be visible via the list. If you modify a variable which basically contains a *copy* of that reference, that won't affect the list at all.

I suspect you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < phoneContacts.size(); i++) {                  
    UserAgenda pc = phoneContacts.get(i);
    for (UserAgenda sc : serverContacts) {
        if (pc.getEmails() != null) {
            ArrayList<String> emailsPc = new ArrayList<String>(pc.getEmails());
            for (String epc: emailsPc) {
                ArrayList<String> emailList = new ArrayList<String>(sc.getEmails());                    
                String emailServer = emailList.get(0);
                if (epc.equals(emailServer)) {
                    pc = sc;
                    // Replace the value in the collection too...
                    phoneContacts.set(i, sc);
                    // Do you want to break here?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's unclear why you're creating the array lists within the loop, by the way... (or why you're recreating the same list of emails on each iteration). Basically the code is *very* unclear at the moment, and I strongly suspect it could be simplified considerably - but it's hard to do so without knowing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Jon, 
I create the ArrayList cause I use HashSet to store my emails. And using an Arraylist is very handy to me.

Comment: @Dayerman: But you can iterate over a HashSet just as easily as you can iterate over an ArrayList - so what benefit do you think your `emailsPc` variable is actually providing?